# My rig is suddently invisible

Tags: rigging, armature

My rig is invisible, I know the bones are there but I just can't see them.
I turned on X-ray, I tried to unhide it and I tried switching different skeleton layers but nothing happened. What else can I do to make the rig appear again, or is my file broken?

Please see my file here:

https://we.tl/t-RJKGWhxgkD

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have turned off the *Bones* in the *Viewport Overlays* menu. Just enable the option to see them again.

[image: bones overlays]

Answer (score 0):

Select the armature in the hierarchy, move to *Pose Mode*, and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd>.